# Komodo Edit 8 - Previewing PHP Files on Local Server

Tags: php, komodo, komodoedit

I am trying to figure out how to correctly use the preview function in Komodo Edit 8.

As of right now, when I press the globe icon to preview my file, one of two things happens:

1. If I select preview in a Komodo Tab, the webview opens up on the bottom of the window, and I am presented with a panel that asks me if I want to save or open the file. If I click open, it gives me a list of other applications, which isn't what I want, and if I click save, the panel goes away, but the webview remains empty (without loading the file). If I then refresh the webview it loads an empty "about:blank" page.
2. If I select preview in chrome, the file opens in chrome, but it opens as `file://localhost/Users/myUserName/Sites/...` which just displays the text of the php file. I need it to open as `http://localhost/~myUserName/...` to actually run the code.

Is there any way to fix this? (I'd like to be able to get it running both in Komodo and Chrome, just to save myself the hassle of opening up chrome and typing in the URL of the file every time.) I tried the "Map URI" feature to map `file://localhost/Users/myUserName/Sites/` to`"http://localhost/~myUserName/` and vice-versa, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer from Komodo support --

Turns out I had to map the URI `http://localhost/~myUserName/` to the path `file:///User/myUserName/Sites/` even though chrome was displaying the path as `file://localhost/User/myUserName/Sites/` for some reason.